# What is the best public transit way to get from Formia, Italy, to Positano Italy in July in regards to time and money?

Tags: italy

We are traveling from Formia to Positano, Italy on a monday morning in early july. Can anyone help me put together the best way to travel WITHOUT a rental car, taking into account time and pricing? We will have luggage with us, not a lot, but enough to make us less free to tour around or walk far.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, we don't know what the best in your opinion is. Most likely there will be some trade-off between time and pricing and we don't know which one you value higher. As it stands, it is likely that this question will be put on hold or closed because it is opinion-based. You can prevent this by making your question more specific so that there is a definitive answer. Maybe look at the related questions on the right to see what kind of questions can be asked here.